# JNK export function call

Tags: java, java-native-interface

i see sample in wiki similar to this:

defination:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     printf("Hello World!\n");
     return;
 }
```

call in java:

```
class HelloWorld
{
    private native void print();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new HelloWorld().print();
    }
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

but when i want to pass a jstring to the function.

What modification need to the defination and the call ?

similar to this :

Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring path)

and

```
private native void print(....)
```

what parameter need to be in the print parameter when call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java part is easy:

```
 private native void print(String path);
```

The C part, not so much:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject obj, jstring path)
 {
    char* arg2 = 0;
    if (path) {
       arg2 = (char *)(*jenv)->GetStringUTFChars(jenv, path, 0);
       if (!arg2) return;
    }

    printf("%s\n", arg2);
    if (arg2) (*jenv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jenv, path, (const char *)arg2);
    return;
 }
```

Comment: why in my eclipse,  its defination of the GetStringUTFChars is    " const char* GetStringUTFChars(jstring string, jboolean* isCopy)
    { return functions->GetStringUTFChars(this, string, isCopy); }"  So i modify our line to "     unsigned char* arg2 = 0;
 jenv->GetStringUTFChars(path, arg2);". what's the problem

Comment: The difference is that's the C++ JNI API, not the C JNI API as I have shown. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp16696) for some similar code contrasting the C and C++ APIs.